# In Django, whitenoise do not show static files?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, whitenoise

I am trying to show static files while `debug=false`.I am using whitenoise library but still website don't show the static files and media files. My settings.py file like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [

    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('',include('games.urls')),
  path('sitemap.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
    path('sentry-debug/', trigger_error),
    path('ajax_calls/search/', autocompleteModel),
   path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Did you specify media/static urls in the `urls.py`?

Comment: You can also add this `whitenoise.runserver_nostatic` in installed apps

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem my urls.py file like this:urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('',include('games.urls')),
  path('sitemap.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
    path('sentry-debug/', trigger_error),
    path('ajax_calls/search/', autocompleteModel),
   path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you collect your static folder

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

and in your main projects urls.py

```
 url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: for using `staticfiles_urlpatterns`:
**this only works when `DEBUG=True` in `settings.py` which means you should NOT use it for production environment.**  ref https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.urls.staticfiles_urlpatterns

Answer (score 3):

**To use `WhiteNoise` with django :**

1. **Make sure staticfiles is configured correctly**

In the project `settings.py` file set

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
This *staticfiles* folder will be the folder where `collectstatic` will pull out all your static files.

2. **Enable WhiteNoise**
   Always in `settings.py`:

   MIDDLEWARE = [

   ```
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    # ...
   ```

   ]

**NB :** The `WhiteNoise middleware` should be placed directly after the `Django SecurityMiddleware` (if you are using it) and before all other middleware.

That is all, but if you want more performance you should enable caching and compression support like this :

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

If you want to apply compression but don’t want the caching behaviour then you can use:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'
```

Follow these steps and all will be ok. [WhiteNoise Documentation](https://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html)