# Django/Wagtail static assets return 404 only when logged in but works logged out

Tags: django, heroku, wagtail, whitenoise, wagtail-admin

After upgrading Wagtail and supporting packages, I'm having a strange problem where all the static assets (CSS, JS, fonts, etc..) return a 404 error when logged into the Wagtail admin, ie. the sessionid is valid and set in the browser. However, the are accessible when not logged in (no sessionid cookie). This is true for the public facing site as well as `/admin`

The site is running:

- Django==4.1.8
- wagtail==4.2.2
- whitenoise==6.4.0
- Python==3.11.2
- hosted via heroku.

Both production and dev (currently locally) are set using `STATICFILES_STORAGE = whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage` and `STATIC_URL = "static/"`. Migrations and `collectstatic` have also been run.

I've tested this a couple of ways:

### Using curl

**No Cookie:**
`curl -I http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/wagtailadmin/js/vendor.610e8c3f47d9.js`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 01 May 2023 06:11:55 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.11.2
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset="utf-8"
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000, public, immutable
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Cookie
Last-Modified: Mon, 01 May 2023 03:59:51 GMT
ETag: "644f3937-41103"
Content-Length: 266499
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

**With Cookie:**
`curl -I http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/wagtailadmin/js/vendor.610e8c3f47d9.js -H "Cookie: csrftoken=fPp7Oq2lR90jkilUiPDRHTOPTsu2lMZm;sessionid=his9jbjahqa3j86hjueeop0lno8pb4a9"`

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 01 May 2023 06:15:53 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.11.2
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2761
Vary: Cookie
```

**Invalid sessionid:**
à la `sessionid=thisisnotvalid` returns assets fine

### Setting full URL for STATIC_URL

*This is where it gets interesting.* If I set `STATIC_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/"` and log in via `http://localhost:8000` everything works perfectly. If I set `STATIC_URL = "http://localhost:8000/static/"` no dice! It's the same if I swap them. Apparently `STATIC_URL` and `WAGTAILADMIN_BASE_URL` cannot be the same.

In production I don't really have the option (or don't want) to serve the assets from a separate domain. I'd expect it to just work as it did formally.

### Debug setting

**DEBUG=True:**
Setting `STATIC_URL` works with `static/` but not when it's the same as the accessing domain and works when set to an alternate.

**DEBUG=False:**
Works as described above. `static/` and matching domains don't work. An alternate does.

### Relevent bits of configs

**base.py:**

```py
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "static"),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
```

**dev.py:**

```py
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"
STATIC_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/"
```

**production.py:**

```py
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"
STATIC_URL = "https://www.domainredacted.com/static/" # Formally just "static/"
```

It's quite late and perhaps I missed something while upgrading but I can't seem to find it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**App & Middleware:**

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ......
    "generic_chooser",
    "django_extensions",
    "storages",  # For S3 Storage
    "wagtail_2fa",
    "django_otp",
    "django_otp.plugins.otp_totp",
    "captcha",
    "wagtailcaptcha",
    "wagtail.contrib.modeladmin",
    "wagtail.contrib.forms",
    "wagtail.contrib.redirects",
    "wagtail.contrib.settings",
    "wagtail.contrib.routable_page",
    "wagtailmetadata",
    "wagtail.embeds",
    "wagtail.sites",
    "wagtail.users",
    "wagtail.snippets",
    "wagtail.documents",
    "wagtail.images",
    "wagtail.search",
    "wagtail.admin",
    "wagtail",
    "wagtail.contrib.search_promotions",
    "wagtail.contrib.table_block",
    "modelcluster",
    "taggit",
    "django.contrib.sitemaps",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "wagtail_2fa.middleware.VerifyUserMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware",
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was something very small. I moved security and whitenoise middleware to the top thanks to this [information from Rvector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69077874/3981632). Not sure why it wasn't an issue previously. Live and learn!

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "wagtail_2fa.middleware.VerifyUserMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware",
]
```